# scaling x and y axis (geom_bar)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am having a trouble plotting what is seemingly simple plot.

```
x <-
  read_excel("Desktop/Book1.xlsx",
             col_types = c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))

x1 <-  gather(hospitals, key = "sector", value = "count", 2:3)



p <- ggplot(data = x1, aes( x = Years, y = count, fill = sector )) +
  geom_col(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 5, colour="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=1, color="white", size=2) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12 )

p


data is 

1   1946    Public hospitals    35
2   1984    Public hospitals    41
3   2000    Public hospitals    65
4   2001    Public hospitals    67
5   2002    Public hospitals    66
6   2003    Public hospitals    76
7   2004    Public hospitals    77
8   2005    Public hospitals    85
9   2006    Public hospitals    90
10  2007    Public hospitals    94
11  2008    Public hospitals    97
12  2009    Public hospitals    102
13  2010    Public hospitals    102
14  1946    Private hospitals   NA
15  1984    Private hospitals   139
16  2000    Private hospitals   325
17  2001    Private hospitals   336
18  2002    Private hospitals   343
19  2003    Private hospitals   364
20  2004    Private hospitals   376
21  2005    Private hospitals   376
22  2006    Private hospitals   353
23  2007    Private hospitals   355
24  2008    Private hospitals   365
25  2009    Private hospitals   370
26  2010    Private hospitals   376
Showing 12 to 26 of 26 entries, 3 total columns
```

and i am ending with this result!
[image: bar blot graph]

first, how can I modify x axis to show the bars separated and only for the years i have data for ? [ can the x axis  around 1960 be omitted and bars squeezed to save space ? 
second, how can the Y axis be fixed ? some bars are higher than their value is!

Comment: Can you give an example of some bars that are higher than their value? The bars are stacked, so I'd expect the total height to be the sum of the two sectors' values for a given year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x1 %>%
  ggplot(aes( x = as.character(Years), y = count, fill = sector )) +
  geom_col(position="stack", colour="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=1, size=2,
            color=ifelse(df$sector != "Public hospitals", "white", "black")) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Year") +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

Edit: Upon reconsideration I realized I did not properly stack the positioning of the text. It happens to look ok with this data, but that's just coincidence. To get the right positioning for the text, one approach is manual: we could sum up the cumulative height for each year:

```
x1 %>%
  group_by(Years) %>%
  mutate(cuml_count = cumsum(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% ....

geom_text(aes(label = count, y = cuml_count), vjust = 1, size = 2,
          color=ifelse(df$sector != "Public hospitals", "white", "black")) +
```